# Is it "あめがふる" or "あめふる"?

Tags: grammar, particle-が

Is が needed to say it's raining? あめ**が**ふっています? Is it okay to omit が in this case?

Comment: Yes, in casual situations. が is often omitted in mangas.

Answer (score 2):

In spoken language, it is more often omitted. In written language, it should generally not be omitted (though exceptions apply).